# I want to get data from different database tables in azure search,is it possible? or any other workaround or best search

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-cognitive-search

My website is hosted on Azure, i want to implement Azure search indexing, but there are some limitations of showing data to anyone. So when i retrieve data from a table, i will check user id and all details from different userrole table and pick some data on the basis of userid,

Can i get data from different database tables using Azure search indexing? currently i am getting onlye one table data on one index?

i have to implement Azure index search, or please suggest me any other workaround for my problem.

for example
i have a table of "users","userroles", "projects" and "tasks".
i want to show tasks of projects related to user. foreign key will be used. now if i create azure index, it will only run my query on tasks table, it will not check the tasks details from projects,users, etc tables. so my question is how i can create such type of index or query in Azure search, where i use different tables to get relevant and correct data in my search.

Comment: Can you describe your problem in somewhat more details? Give an example of sample data as to how the data would change based on the user id.

Comment: i updated the question and added my table name and some scenario. please review it. if still some confusion, i will show some test data and tables for better understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add those roles on your Azure Search index, specifying which roles have access, and use Odata to filter the results.

https://.search.windows.net/indexes//docs?search=&$filter=Administrator%20eq%20true

You can learn more about filters on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/odata-expression-syntax-for-azure-search#filter-syntax) documentation.